# How do I make a JButton move to an empty tile?

Tags: java, jbutton

So I got an assignment in Java to make an 8 piece puzzle, and I chose to use `JButtons` for tiles (don't know if that's even possible). I've got the buttons to appear in a random order when starting it, but I have no idea how to make the tiles able to move when you click on them. So I'm wondering if someone could just point me in the right direction? I've come to conclusion that I need to use `Actionlistners` and saw an old user here getting tip of doing `Actionlistners` on every button, but I am having trouble with knowing what to writ, and do I put this in another class?

Any help is very much appreciated!

The product so far:

[image: Embedded a picture of the product so far]

Comment: If you go ahead with using buttons for your tiles, then when a button is clicked you have to figure out the button's current position, figure out where it needs to move it, and adjust the layout of the buttons to match. Good luck.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your title so it has more sentence type structure, this is easier to read. I also fixed the grammar in the body of the question, so it is more readable. Another thing I did was format the class titles as code using back ticks. I would recommend adding the code that you already have; this will allow others to find bugs and add onto it. Hope you get your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easier, you could add ninth button which is transparent and not clickable. Every but should has his id, which would also tell hes position.

```
11 12 13
21 22 22
31 32 33
```

So for every button you already assign his random number. Now just like you use actionlistners to detect which button is clicked. And when is clicked you check if button that is neighbor is transparent. If transparent you would swap there values, one would become visible,other transparent and not clickable.

To get button neighbors you would use + and - operations.

```
int leftNeighbour = id - 1;
int rightNeighbour = id + 1;
int topNeighbour = id - 10;
int bottomtNeighbour = id + 10;
```

I assume that all buttons are saved in an array so you just go like this:

```
for(Button tempButton : Buttons)
{
   if(leftNeighbour > 0 && leftNeighbour == tempButton.id) //we check first if button id is OK, then we compere it with tempButtons id
   {
      int tempButtonValue = tempButton.value;
      tempButton.value = currentButton.value;
      currentButton.value = tempButtonValue ;
      makeButtonTransparent(tempButton);
      break; //we found over neighbor so we can stop for loop
   }
   //then you check conditions for other neighbor id's. Butt first condition is allays different
}
```

I hope that I didn't make it over complicated, but this is idea that I got in few minutes, when I was thinking how I would make it with buttons. There is probably some better way to set ID's to buttons, and check if they are neighbors.